# keep alive thread in PyQt4

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4, qthread

I have a PyQt4 application, which at some point packs a big file using the tarfile module. Since the tarfile module does not implement any callback strategy, it blocks and the Qt GUI gets unresponsive.

I want the GUI to keep updating during that time. The only possibility is a separate thread.
So, I start a QThread. What do I have to do in the QThread to make the GUI update itself?
As soon, as the tar process is finished, I want the thread to finish.

Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QThread's are pretty much identical to normal Python threads so you can just use normal communication methods. However, QThreads also have a few signals available, so if you simply connect to those, than you're done.

In your GUI code do something like this and you're pretty much done:

```
thread = Thread()
thread.finished.connect(gui.do_update_thingy)
```

There is also a `terminated` and `started` signal available which you can use :)

Comment: Thanks, but what I am wondering is which function I have to call for the gui to update.

Comment: What kind of GUI update are you looking for? You can simply connect any slot to the signal and it will work :)

Comment: I want the gui to redraw (if it thinks it is necessary) and to react to user input

Comment: Man, I am blind to what you want to tell me. Put the tarfile progress in a seperate thread. Yeah, good Idea :). Thanks.